# Ajuda com uma Grid em Bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia, gostaria de saber como faço para que minhas imagens da Grid fiquem alinhadas lado a lado e não umas dentro das outras.
[image: Já tentei o <code>class="img-thumbnail"</code> mas não funcionou.]

Comment: Olá @art0s, coloque o código do se grid cujo as imagens estão estão alinhadas umas dentro das outras.

Comment: Edita sua pergunta é coloca o que vc já tem de código, sem isso não da pra ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo abaixo você vai precisar modificar.

Aconselho você ler a documentação do [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) assim você se sentira mais confortável quando for desenvolver paginas responsivas...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-danger">Sua imagem maior</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 bg-success">As menores</div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-primary">Lado a lado</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-danger">Sua imagem maior</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 bg-success">As menores</div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-primary">Lado a lado</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Obrigado, andei fazendo uma gambiarra e parece que funcionou, mas obrigado pela dica, vou dar uma olhada na documentação.